# Signing and Email - Cannot find the original signer

Tags: .net, x509certificate

I have the following code however when I run the code I receive the error **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Cannot find the original signer.**,
why does this occur? Is it due to an incorrect setup of my certificates?

```
    public byte[] GetSignature(string message, X509Certificate2 signingCertificate,
                               X509Certificate2 encryptionCertificate)
    {
        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        SignedCms signedCms = new SignedCms(new ContentInfo(messageBytes), true);

        CmsSigner cmsSigner = new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.IssuerAndSerialNumber, signingCertificate);
        cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;

        if (encryptionCertificate != null)
        {
            cmsSigner.Certificates.Add(encryptionCertificate);
        }

        Pkcs9SigningTime signingTime = new Pkcs9SigningTime();
        cmsSigner.SignedAttributes.Add(signingTime);

        signedCms.ComputeSignature(cmsSigner, false);

        return signedCms.Encode();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to delete this line:

```
cmsSigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
```

I had the same problem as you describe, I also used the `WholeChain` option, omitting it solved the problem for me. I hope it will help others even though the question was posted 8 months ago.